# Failure of periodic cyclic homology to be a localizing invariant

Tags: hochschild-homology, cyclic-homology

A localizing invariant $E: dgcat_{sm} \rightarrow Ch_k$ from small dg categories to chain complexes over a field $k$ (say $k = \mathbb{C}$) is a dg functor which sends localization sequences to exact triangles, commutes with filtered colimits, and inverts Morita equivalences.  Hochschild homology is a localizing invariant, and so is cyclic homology, but negative cyclic and periodic cyclic homology are not because defining them involves a limit.  In particular, though they both send localization sequences to exact triangles and invert Morita equivalences, they do not commute with filtered colimits.

There is a localizing invariant $HP^{flt}$ which is the same as $HP$ on homotopically finitely presented categories and results from forcing $HP$ to commute with filtered colimits.  I'm interested in situations where $HP \simeq HP^{flt}$; e.g. given a mixed complex $(V, d, b)$, the $S^1$-invariants are given by a colimit $(V[[u]], d + ub) \simeq (V[u], d + ub)$ as long as $V$ is cohomologically bounded below (this seems to work sometimes even if $V$ is not cohomologically bounded below if the periodic cyclic homology is "small" enough).

What is a (pathological?  non-pathological?) example where this actually fails?  And, how "important" is this failure to commute with filtered colimits?  (More generallly, why is it important to insist that localizing invariants commute with filtered colimits?)

Comment: So, my (admittedly limited) understanding is that asking for invariants to commute with filtered colimits is just a way to avoid set-theoretic issues (one of the few times I actually encountered such issues in actual mathematical problems). You can still hope for $HP$ to be corepresentable in noncommutative motives (and in fact I'd believe that easily), but of course not by a compact object.